# cant install ubuntu on usb: installation freezes on async_tx:…

Tags: boot, usb, live-usb, usb-installation, 23.10

im trying to install ubuntu on my asus zypherus m16 (2021) gaming laptop.
it has a intel core i9, nvidia rtx 3060 mobile, i believe it has 16 gb of ram, and 1 tb of storage.

im using a 32gb flashdrive i put the iso in with gnome disks.

every time i try to install ubuntu i try to use install/try. it goes through the commands but gets stuck on “async_tx: api initialized (async)” i cant get further past this and it is stuck. what do i do?

i cant use no graphics mode because the ubuntu installer crashes and wont wont on there.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, but then i tried to boot up with safe graphics and it worked for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1343402)